# Container height not expanding to fit content resulting in overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I tried to work with flexboxes but am having trouble with it.

This is how it should look:

[image: This is how it should look.]

As soon as the display is too small, the content either overflows the nested flexbox or (while I tried to fix it myself) the nested flexbox overflows the main flexbox.

Bug:

[image: Bug]

```css
html,
body,
.viewport {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11pt;
}

body {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header,
article,
section,
footer {
  padding: 2em;
}

header {
  background-color: red;
}

article {
  background-color: aqua;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

section {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.offer {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

footer {
  background-color: forestgreen;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>
<article>
  Article
</article>
<section>
  <div class="offer">orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentes</div>
  <div class="offer">O2</div>
  <div class="offer">O3</div>
</section>
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```

Comment: You need a `min-height` on the body, not `height`

Comment: @LGSon Made the overflow bug work but now there is whitespace below the footer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the container to expand with the content, then don't use a fixed height.

Use `min-height` instead.

[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/3qpzox3h/)

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh; /* allows container to expand with growing content */
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11pt;
}
body > * {
  padding: 2em;
}
header {
  background-color: red;
}
article {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: aqua;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.offer {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
footer {
  background-color: forestgreen;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<article>Article</article>
<section>
  <div class="offer">orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentes</div>
  <div class="offer">O2</div>
  <div class="offer">O3</div>
</section>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for, but you could add 
       "flex-wrap: wrap; "
to the .section (yellow background). That will cause the boxes to stack vertically when they don't have enough space, and keep all of your content inside of the correct borders. The default setting for wrapping is no wrap, which is why your content squishing together like that.